# Prove $\sqrt{1-e^{-1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int^1_0 e^{-x^2}dx<\sqrt{1-e^{-2}}.$

Tags: definite-integrals

## Problem

Prove $$\sqrt{1-e^{-1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int^1_0 e^{-x^2}dx<\sqrt{1-e^{-2}}.$$

## Attempt

Since $$ \forall x\in[0,1],\quad e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\,x^{2n}$$
and by integrating termwise  over $[0,1]$ we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\,n!}.$$
This will help?

Comment: The lower bound is not correct... The value of the integral is approx. 0.421 and the "lower bound" is approx. 0.795.

Comment: @PierreCarre Did you multiply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$?

Comment: I did, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^1 e^ {-x^2} dx \approx. 0.421$ and $\sqrt{1-e^{-1}} \approx 0.795$.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* you have a multiplication by 2 in the integral, otherwise the lower bound does not hold (as @PierreCarre noted).

Squaring, we want to prove
$$
1-e^{-1}<\frac4\pi\iint_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}e^{-x^2-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y<1-e^{-2}
$$
Noting that the unit square $[0,1]^2$ is squeezed(*) between the quarter discs of radius 1 and radius $\sqrt{2}$, and
$$
\int_0^a e^{-r^2}r\,\mathrm{d}r=\frac{1-e^{-a^2}}{2}
\quad
\text{and}\quad
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac4\pi\,\mathrm{d}\theta=2
$$
give our two bounds.

---

(*): We have for all $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$, that $r^2=x^2+y^2\leq 2$ and $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2]$.  On the other hand, for $r\leq 1$ and $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2]$, we have $x=r\cos\theta\in[0,1]$ and $y=r\sin\theta\in[0,1]$.  So
$$
(0\leq r\leq 1,0\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi2)\subseteq[0,1]^2\subseteq
(0\leq r\leq\sqrt2,0\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi2).
$$

Comment: Can we prove it without squaring? Namely, just consider one variable integral?

Comment: Maybe, but the $\sqrt{}$ on both ends are screaming for you to square.

Comment: @user10354138 How is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ squeezed between the quarter discs?

Comment: @PierreCarre I've just edited to include the points you raised.